# Comparing iterator value_type in range constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I'm writing a range cosntructor for a custom container:

```
MyContainer(const InputIterator& first, 
            const InputIterator& last, 
            const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type())
```

and would like to check that the the `InputIterator::value_type` is compatible with the container's `value_type`. I initially tried tried:

```
static_assert(!(std::is_convertible<InputIterator::value_type, value_type>::value ||
        std::is_same<InputIterator::value_type, value_type>::value), "error");
```

and went as far as:

```
using InputIteratorType = typename std::decay<InputIterator>::type;
using InputValueType = typename std::decay<InputIteratorType::value_type>::type;
static_assert(!(std::is_convertible<InputValueType, value_type>::value ||
        std::is_same<InputValueType, value_type>::value), "error");
```

but it always asserts, even when I use the `MyContainer::iterator` as the input iterator.

How can I check that the `InputIterator` is compatible?

Comment: You are asserting the exact opposite of the condition that you want to be true. Remove the `!` from the expressions and each of these `static_assert`s will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you probably want [`std::is_constructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible):

```
static_assert(std::is_constructible<
    value_type,
    decltype(*first)
    >::value, "error");
```

Or, alternatively, [`std::is_assignable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable), depending on whether you're constructing or assigning from the input iterators.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're onto something with `iterator_traits`, but the assertion still goes off even for the containers own iterators.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus Without a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I can't do any better than guess. What is `value_type`? What are you constructing `Container` with? etc.

Comment: swap the order of value_type and the dependent typename and then it works! thanks!

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus If you swap them, you're testing if the InputIterator's value_type is constructible from yours. That is not a reasonable thing to test...

Comment: This asserts that the container's `value_type` is constructible from an *rvalue* expression with the iterator's `value_type`. Given that new container elements are being constructed from the expression `*foo` for some `InputIterator` `foo`, `std::is_constructible<value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::reference>` is more precise.

Comment: @Casey Switched to just use the actual type of the expression.